# JS Object is showing undefined in LWC function call

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

This is the function I'm trying to call from my function. It's erring on the last line here because selectedOption is undefined.

```
handleStatusChange(event) {
  console.log('status change event: ' + event.detail.value);
  event.stopPropagation();
  const { currentTarget, detail } = event;
  const { selectedOption, context } = detail;
  const { value, label } = selectedOption;
```

I think there's a hierarchy here: event has detail, detail has selectedOption, selectedOption has value.

In my function, I only care about passing 'value'. Why is selected selectedOption undefined?

```
    this.handleStatusChange({ 
      detail: () => {
        selectedOption: () => {
          value: 'Pitched'
        }
      },
      stopPropagation: () => {}
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`() => {}` is the Arrow function syntax. You haven't created objects, so much as functions. For normal objects, use `{}` instead:

```
this.handleStatusChange({ 
  detail: {
    selectedOption: {
      value: 'Pitched'
    }
  },
  stopPropagation: () => {}
});
```